# No components are shown in the nexus bower proxy repository

Tags: bower, nexus, nexus3

I had setup a proxy repository for `bower (http://bower.herokuapp.com)` as per [Nexus Document](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/bower.html). After running `bower install` command, nothing was shown in the components section. 
All the files were downloaded to `bower_components` of my local directory. But it is not available in the nexus components. 
It always try to download libraries directly from internet instead of caching it.

My `.bowerrc` configuration,

```
{
  "directory": "bower_components",
  "registry": {
    "search": [
      "http://localhost:8081/repository/repo-all"
    ],
    "register": "http://usr:pas@localhost:8081/repository/repo-internal"
  },
  "resolvers": [
    "bower-nexus3-resolver"
  ],
  "nexus": {
    "username": "usr",
    "password": "pas"
  }
}
```

Comment: Couple of questions for you, what does your bower.json file look like for the project, and also, where is the location of your .bowerrc?

Comment: Also, if you can provide the console log from running a bower install command that would be helpful.